# Flash Builder breaks even though there is no break point

Tags: flash, breakpoints, builder, resume

Flash Builder breaks in a specific line even though there is no break point (and never was).
I can get passed this by pressing F8 (resume), but it is annoying.
 
 
I've tried Project => Clean with no luck.
I've tried toggling break point in that line on/off with no luck.
 
If I comment out the line it breaks a line later.
If I rewrite the line, it usually does not break at that line anymore - and sometimes solves the problem for a while - a week later it will break somewhere near.
 
If I copy the problematic area into a flat text editor and back again, the problem remains.

What to do?

Comment: How are we suppose to help you? Paste some code.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder stores information about breakpoints in a file called ".markers". You need to close Flash Builder and delete this file. All breakpoints for selected project will be cleared.
This file is located here:

```
YOUR_PATH_TO_FB_WORKBENCH\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\.markers
```

For me it is:

```
c:\Users\Administrator\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\TestASProject\.markers
```

Comment: It did not do it for me, although I'm sure it is the way to go - because renaming the as-file fixed it. Like: filename.as => filename_.as. This is a workaround and not the perfect solution.